# How to get triangles list of a "STL" file?

Tags: 3d, cad

I want to make a low-poly sculpture from a "STL" file that I created. the simplest way to make the sculpture is to have a list of triangles. Edge lengths and angles.
Is there a way to get this data out of the "STL" file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to know to load STL files, both binary and ASCII: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)